# MS Access Chart Showing Dates Not Found in Dataset

Tags: ms-access

The following chart is showing dates that are not found in the underlying dataset.  Below are images of the chart, the SQL statement used to populate the chart and a gridview of the SQL statement.  How does one configure the chart to only show dates that are in the dataset.  I don't want to show Saturday and Sunday.

```
TRANSFORM Sum([Hours]) AS [SumOfHrs] 
SELECT (cstr(Format([ReportDate],"DDDDD"))) FROM [2013_4_30_TimeTrack] 
WHERE ((([2013_4_30_TimeTrack].CreatedBy)="Tim Odell")) 
GROUP BY (Int([ReportDate])),(Format([ReportDate],"DDDDD")) 
PIVOT [ProjectName];
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that if the chart control knows that the x-axis column is `Date/Time` then it might try to be "helpful" and fill in the missing dates for you. If that is the case then you could try tweaking your query so that column is `Text` (e.g., by using `Format([DateField], "Short Date")` and see if that works better for you.

### Edit

Try this: Open the report in Design View and double-click the chart control. From the Microsoft Graph menu bar, choose `Chart > Chart Options...`, then on the "Axes" tab select "Category" for the "Category (X) axis".

[image: category.png]

Comment: I agree. This is what a charting tool ought to be doing. If the time scale has gaps, the gaps should be shown.

Comment: I agree it is trying to be "helpful" and I was thinking that the statement Format([ReportDate],"DDDDD") contained in the SQL statement would override the helpfulness but it does not appear to be taking hold.